# get task id's from kafka connect API to print in logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect sink code for which below json is passed as curl command to register tasks.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea on how to get the task id's of my connect. For example in below example, we have defined max tasks is 3, so I need to know
the name of 3 tasks for logs i.e. I need to know which line of my log belongs to which task.

In below example, I know I have 3 tasks - `TestCheck-1`, `TestCheck-2` and `TestCheck-3` based on the kafka connect logs. I want to know how to get the task names so that I can print them in my kafka connect log lines.

```
{
        "name": "TestCheck",
        "config": {
                "topics": "topic1",
                "connector.class": "ApplicationSinkTask Class package",
                "tasks.max": "3",
                "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
                "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
                "connector.url": "jdbc connection url",
                "driver.name": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                "username": "myusername",
                "password": "mypassword",
                "table.name": "test_table",
                "database.name": "test",
        }
}
```

When I register, I will get below details.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @myjson.json http://service:8082/connectors

{"name":"TestCheck","config":{"topics":"topic1","connector.class":"ApplicationSinkTask Class package","tasks.max":"3","key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","connector.url":"jdbc:sqlserver://datahubprod.database.windows.net:1433;","driver.name":"jdbc connection url","username":"myuser","password":"mypassword","table.name":"test_table","database.name":"test","name":"TestCheck"},"tasks":[{"connector":"TestCheck","task":0},{"connector":"TestCheck","task":1},{"connector":"TestCheck","task":2}],"type":null}
```

Comment: Probably would only be possible with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3816

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the connectors with the Kafka Connect Rest API. There's a whole heap of commands which you can find [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing.html#common-rest-examples)

The example given in the above link shows you can retrieve all task for a given connector using the command

```
$ curl localhost:8083/connectors/local-file-sink/tasks
[
  {
    "id": {
      "connector": "local-file-sink",
      "task": 0
    },
    "config": {
      "task.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkTask",
      "topics": "connect-test",
      "file": "test.sink.txt"
    }
  }
]
```

You can use a language of your choice to send the `curl` command and import the json response into a variable/dictionary for further use, such as printing to a log. Here's a very simple example using python which will assign the whole output to a variable.

```
import requests
import json

connectors = 'http://localhost:8083/connectors'
p = requests.get(connectors)
data = p.json()
```

If you parse the `data` variable to a a dictionary, you can the access each element, i.e the `task id`

I hope this helps!